# Why C++ compilers have many optimization levels

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I was just thinking why C++ compilers have many optimization levels like O1, O2 etc. Why can everything be part of just one optimization level O.

I tried search online a lot but didn't got a convincing answer for this.

Comment: Because there are different goals for optimization (size, speed, debugging)

Comment: @M.M - So do you mean roughly speaking -O1 is for size, -O2 for speed and so on?

Comment: Read your compiler's documentation to see what each one does

Comment: That's not many. Many is all the valid combinations of more precise flags like gcc's hundreds of flags like -funroll-loops, -finline-functions-called-once, etc.

Comment: Like @M.M says, if you have ever tried stepping thorugh maximally-optimized code with a debugger, you would understand.  I have seen 'this' as incorrect/NULL for several lines into a method that access instance vars correctly, then suddenly 'this' appears with the correct value:(

Comment: @M.M: Re “Because there are different goals for optimization (size, speed, debugging)”: That would answer why there are optimization switches with different goals (size, speed, debugging). It does not answer why there are different optimization levels.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the different levels have different tradeoffs between the goals

Comment: There are different optimization levels to satisfy compilation duration, executable performance and executable size.  More optimization levels present more choices for the User of the compiler.  There is the *time vs. space* tradeoff.  Some optimization levels may use more code space to increase performance.  Some applications (such as embedded systems) may not have a lot of memory available, but want some kind of performance boost.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: your comment is a better answer than either of the two posted so far.

Comment: @M.M: And the question asks about those.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head: optimizing takes time (more optimization means slower compilation), debugging optimized code can be more difficult, more aggressive optimization can reveal bugs, you can optimize for different things (program size, speed, etc.)…

Answer (score 1):

While compilers are smart enough to optimize several common commands (O1) they may try with not-so-frequent strategies (O2) and even with corner cases (O3).

Whether the resulting code is more optimized depends a lot on the original code, and sometimes on the CPU hardware. The only way to tell which "O" is best is trying and measuring running times.

Remember that the one who really knows about the code is you. Write it with part of your brain thinking about how fast it will run.

Comment: Disagree with the last paragraph. IMO you should write the code so that it is easy to maintain, and let the compiler do the optimizing

Comment: @M.M: If it doesn't manage to crawl its way to the finish line, it doesn't matter how easy to maintain it is. So, keeping an eye on writing reasonably performant code is a must. Remember that moderation is a virtue.

Comment: @M.M *Easy to maintain* is undoubtedly true. But read my last sentence again: "part of your brain", not the whole of it.

Comment: @M.M: Ripi2 is correct. Prioritising expressive code that's easy to maintain is important, but you can't just wilfully forget that your code has to be executed. That's how ludicrously poorly designed programs come about and no amount of optimisation is going to elide that tarnish from your project. Worst case you bake it into your design so badly that you can't even reasonably clean it up later. Bang, technical debt from day dot. _(cont.)_

Comment: @M.M: _(cont.)_ As with everything, it is a _balance_ and a good programmer will indeed have half an eye on the ball at all times. You don't even necessarily have to make decisions based on what you see, right away... just be aware of it. I consider that to be minimum due diligence.

Answer (score 0):

For precisely two reasons:

- There is no one sequence of compiler optimizations that can simultaneously optimize all possible program characteristics of interest, such as execution time, compilation time, code size, energy consumption, binary-portability, etc. In compiler optimizations research, this is known as the phase ordering problem.
- Most developers do not want to bother with figuring out which compiler optimizations to use and in what order; they just want to use whatever is generally recommended in a small number of common scenarios.

That's why compiler developers have decided to offer a small collection of optimization levels from which developers can easily choose in general, yet [offering hundreds of fine-grained optimization options](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00451106/) for advanced scenarios.

The term "optimization levels" is really a misnomer, since they are not exactly "levels" with respect to each other. A better term would be something like "optimization groups".

[Designing optimization levels](http://users.elis.ugent.be/~leeckhou/papers/cgo08.pdf) is a complicated matter for compilers that target a broad range of programs and architectures, such as GCC, Clang, icc, and VC++. Many research papers have been published in the past decade that show that the optimization levels offered by compilers are far from being the best for a particular program, target architecture, or specific collection thereof. This motivated a line of research on [compiler auto-tuning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04405), which can be considered as an approach that falls somewhere in between offering few optimization levels and offering fine-grained control over compiler optimizations.

In summary, optimization levels provide an important convenience for developers, which will be required for many decades to come.